# Scala floating point interpolation formatting specification?

Tags: scala, floating-point

I've been toying around with Scala's floating point interpolation feature but I can't really totally understand its rules. Could anyone shed light in what the different components of the formatting are?

```
println(f"${1234.5678}%1.2f") // prints 1234.57
println(f"${1234.5678}%1.5f") // prints 1234.56780
println(f"${1234.5678}%09.2f") // prints 001234.57
println(f"${1234.5678}%9.2f") // prints "  1234.57"
```

For example, is it possible to left pad the string with any other different character than `' '` or `0`? Is it possible when rounding to just chop off decimal places instead of rounding them as it actually does in the examples above?

Thanks

Comment: Just guessing by similarity to C formatting: “%w.pf” produces p digits after the decimal point and at least w characters total (more if the value requires it).

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, scala `f` use java `System.out.printf` formatter.

If you look at `src.zip!\java\util\Formatter.java`, you could see something like follows:

```
// parse those flags which may be provided by users
private static Flags parse(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case '-': return LEFT_JUSTIFY;
        case '#': return ALTERNATE;
        case '+': return PLUS;
        case ' ': return LEADING_SPACE;
        case '0': return ZERO_PAD;
        case ',': return GROUP;
        case '(': return PARENTHESES;
        case '<': return PREVIOUS;
        default:
                  throw new UnknownFormatFlagsException(String.valueOf(c));
    }
}
```

Here you can see just above symbol supports, cannot customize your own, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

```
println (f"${1234.5678}%1.2f") // prints 1234.57
```

2 decimal places. 1 Place in total is too few, to display the whole number, which has 4+dot+2 = digits at least

```
println (f"${1234.5678}%1.5f") // prints 1234.56780
```

Like above: 1 in total is too few. 4+dot+5= 10 in reality

```
println (f"${1234.5678}%09.2f") // prints 001234.57
```

9 in total, filled with zeros, 2 after delimiter fits.

```
println (f"${1234.5678}%9.2f") // prints "  1234.57"
```

9 in total, filled with spaces, 2 after delimiter fits.

So the numbers %T.Rf are the total width=T and the decimal places are R. But if the number doesn't fit, the layout is sacrificed for correctness. Better you know how much to pay, how hot the cpu is or whatever the number shows - the JVM doesn't know. So T should always be bigger than R (+ 1 for the delimiter).